# SQL function PIVOT with 2 column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have this query on SQL Developer :

> SELECT A.order_number, A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID, C.CHARGE_NAME, C.CHARGE_VALUE 
>   from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B ,TABLE3 C
>   where C.list_line_id=B.list_line_id AND C.line_id=A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID and A.order_number ='4411001286'

that extract this 4 columns:

```
ORDER_NUMBER    LINE_NUMBER     CHARGE_NAME                     CHARGE_VALUE

4411001286      9438572         H Ar                              -639,31
4411001286      9438572         TC Tot                             10867
4411001286      9438572         MN PreV                             6500
4411001286      9438572         LO Offloading                       1200
4411001286      9438572         Costi trasporto                     6500
4411001286      9438572         ML_ICP Machine Line s/n           -24427,69
4411001286      9482805         TC Tot                              23364
4411001286      9482805         H Arr                                0,05
4411001286      9482805         LO Off                               1200
4411001286      9482805         MN Prev Maintenance                  6500
4411001286      9482805         Costi trasporto                      6500
4411001286      9482805         J Margine Ufficio di Rappresentanza  29726
4411001286      9482805         O_ICP Installation                   11954
4411001286      9482805         ML_ICP Machine Line s/n             24427,69
4411001286      9482805         L_ICP 3^ party inst Intercompany        860
```

i need the query to extract that result (starded from the first query):

```
ORDER_NUMBER  LINE_NUMBER  NAME1    VALUE1    NAME2   VALUE2  NAME3   VALUE3..
4411001286    9438572      H Ar     -639,31   TC TOT  10867   MN Prev  6500...
4411001286    9482805      TC ToT    23364    H Arr   0,05    LO Off   1200...
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? `mysql` <> `postgresql` <>`sql-server`. I have removed these conflicting tags, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49861836/edit) your question with the correct one, and **only** the correct one.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server <> Postgres!!!!  Which one is this???

Comment: sorry i wronge. I use SQL DEveloper.

Comment: please provide column names

Comment: the name of coloms for the first query are: 1) order_number 2) line_number 3) name 4)value. The name of coloms for the second table are: 1) order_number  2)line_number 3)name1 4)value1 5)name2 6)value2 7)name3 8)value3 9)name4 10)value4 ecc...

Comment: Edit your post @filippo, don't comment. And I can't say I've heard of an RDBMS called "SQL Developer". Do you mean Oracle SQL Developer (which is simply Oracle). An RDBMS that, ironically, was one you didn't initially tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select order_number, line_number, 
     isnull(max(case when linenum=1 then name else null end),'') name1 ,
     isnull(max(case when linenum=1 then value else null end),'') value1,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=2 then name  else null end),'') name2,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=2 then  value else null end),'') value2,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=3 then name  else null end),'') name3,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=3 then  value else null end),'') value3,
            isnull(max(case when linenum=4 then name  else null end),'') name4,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=4 then  value else null end),'') value4,
            isnull(max(case when linenum=5 then name  else null end),'') name5,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=5 then  value else null end),'') value5,
            isnull(max(case when linenum=6 then name  else null end),'') name6,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=6 then  value else null end),'') value6,
            isnull(max(case when linenum=7 then name  else null end),'') name7,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=7 then  value else null end),'') value7,
             isnull(max(case when linenum=8 then name  else null end),'') name8,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=8 then  value else null end),'') value8,
             isnull(max(case when linenum=9 then name  else null end),'') name9,
      isnull(max(case when linenum=9 then  value else null end),'') value9
          from (select *, row_number() over(partition by order_number, line_number  order by order_number, line_number) linenum
 from (SELECT A.order_number, A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID, C.CHARGE_NAME, C.CHARGE_VALUE from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B ,TABLE3 C where C.list_line_id=B.list_line_id AND C.line_id=A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID and A.order_number ='4411001286')b)a
          group by order_number, line_number
```

Comment: i use SQL Developer

Comment: is not more easy use the function PIVOT?

Comment: dont think that will accomplish what you are looking for in this case - would be easier if u were using sql server

Comment: ok i edited again - try this its simpler - let me know if this works better for you

Comment: i can't use INTO. I need a query that do that

Comment: it's not work. what is '+'? i want a column with name and a column with value

Comment: + is used for concatenation - what error are you getting?

Comment: i don't want to concatenate value. I want 2 rows with order_number line_number  name1 value1 name2 value2 name3 value3 name4 value4...The number of column (name and value) not null in order to the number of charges for the line order. But all as a column, not concatenate.

Comment: ok so just replace '+' with ',' and that will separate into columns for you

Comment: ok. And i replace my query to #temp1?I don't undestand the part after the from.Can you write the query please?Because i have a select to extract that data

Comment: just replace all occurrences of #temp1 with your table name and it should work

Comment: i have not a table.It's a query ( a select..from.. where..) that extract data as in the example.Do you undestand?

Comment: not following - how are you creating your dataset then?

Comment: I do a query that extract the data as in the example. The data of the example are not a table but they are the data extract from a select order_number,line_number.charge_name,charge_value from table1,table2, table3 with some join.

Comment: you have no query written in the example- you will have to explain further if you'd like additional help

Comment: this is the query that i use to extract the data of the example:SELECT A.order_number, 
A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID,
C.CHARGE_NAME,
C.CHARGE_VALUE
from  TABLE1 A,
TABLE2 B
,TABLE3 C
where C.list_line_id=B.list_line_id
AND C.line_id=A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID
and A.order_number ='4411001286'

Comment: Can you update also the part of the column?Because i not see the column of name1, name2,name3,name ecc.. and value1, value2, value3,value4,value5..I don't want the concatenation

Comment: it not works. The error is ORA-00923: parola chiave FROM non trovata dove prevista
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: try fixing your original query SELECT A.order_number, A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID, C.CHARGE_NAME, C.CHARGE_VALUE from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B ,TABLE3 C where C.list_line_id=B.list_line_id AND C.line_id=A.TOP_MODEL_LINE_ID and A.order_number ='4411001286'- it works fine on my end when i write the data to a table manually and run the code

Comment: the problem is do that from a query and not from a table